# How to add a loading bar for a program that always runs and already has code?

Tags: python, discord.py, python-3.11

My code is fairly long, and it needs to always run (discord.py bot). I want to add a loading bar while it loads up so that it tells the User that the program is starting and not frozen or broken.

I already googled and asked chatgpt, but neither have resulted in answers that fit with my needs. The results I found all need me to have the entire code inside another command that terminates once it's fully loaded up, which would break my code. I expect it to start with a loading bar that finishes once the program fully loaded up, and keeps the program running.

Comment: Where will this loading bar be displayed? Have you considred printing to the console at critical moments to indicate that a part of the process has finished?

Comment: The loading bar will be displayed in the console. I currently a print statement for it at the start and near the end, with the discord.py information inside it (as it force-prints it). I mainly want a loading bar so I can learn how they work, and because a loading bar looks considerably nicer than lines of pure text.

Comment: Do you know what makes the loading of your code slow? Is there a specific part where you spend most of your time, like loading cogs, pre-computing some data, downloading files, or just importing a very big module? This can help us give an answer that will be easier to adapt to your actual code.

Comment: It's mostly the time it takes to connect to the internet and get into a proper connection with Discord.

Answer (score 2):

The [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) library is often used to make progress bars.

A simple example is given below. Without more details on what makes your code slow to load, it's hard to be more specific:

```py
from tqdm import tqdm

with tqdm(total=3, desc="Loading bot") as pbar:
    do_slow_stuff()
    pbar.update()
    do_slow_stuff()
    pbar.update()
    run_bot()
```

Answer (score 0):

I once wanted to gather weather information on Google and then print it in the terminal. Here is the code for that, I saved it in a file call weather.py:

```
from time import *
from selenium import webdriver

def weather(info):
    if info:
        # path to chrome driver
        PATH = "/home/shawn31/Documents/chromedriver"
        #######################################################################################################################
        # not open the browser
        user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36"
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.headless = True
        options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
        options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
        options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
        options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
        options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
        options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
        options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
        options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH, options=options)
        #######################################################################################################################
        # open the browser headless
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=current+weather")
        # extracting informating from url
        weather = driver.find_element_by_id("wob_dc")
        temperature = driver.find_element_by_id("wob_tm")
        weather = weather.text
        temperature = temperature.text
        # quit the web page
        driver.quit()
        # print results
        sleep(1)
        print(f" It is {weather} and the temperature is {temperature}°C")
```

If you want to run the weather function, you must download a chromedriver : https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjCyOPww9yBAxU8cvEDHcpzD2YQFnoECBkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchromedriver.chromium.org%2Fdownloads&usg=AOvVaw2Eziwaoh6-1UgCajyO_O8n&opi=89978449

However, this code takes some time to run because of internet connection. So, I wanted to create like a loading screen. And this is what I coded,

```
    # Import modules
import time
import multiprocessing as mltp
# -------------------------- #

# Import functions
from weather import weather
# ------------------------- #


def loading():
     x = ["|", "/", "-", "\\", "-", "|"]

     i = 0

     while True:
          try:
               print("Gathering weather " + x[i], end = "\r")
               i += 1
               time.sleep(0.7)
          except:
               i = 0

# Processing loading and weather function at the same time
p1 = mltp.Process(target=weather, args=[True])
p2 = mltp.Process(target=loading)

# Start the 2 processes
p1.start()
p2.start()

# Check whether the first process is over
p1.join()
# Kill the second process when the first one is over
p2.kill()
```

It uses multiprocessing. The loading animation and the weather function is running at the same time.

It is not exactly a loading bar though. I do not know if my answer is going to help you.

Answer (score 0):

## Info

When we print to the console the `print()` statement in python automatically adds a newline character (`\n`)to the end of your string.

`\n` is an example of an escape seqeunce, there are a couple of diffrent escape sequences that do that have different effects. a list can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/vi/i/7.1?topic=set-escape-sequences). In this list we also have `\r` or Carriage Return. This will be important to us for solving your problem

## Solution

we need to change the end of our printed line from `\n` -> `\r`. In python this can be accomplished with the `end` parameter in the `print()` function

```py
import time
print("Loading: ..........", end="\r")
time.sleep(2)
print("Loading: #......... ", end="\r")
time.sleep(2)
print("Loading: ##........ ", end="\r")
time.sleep(2)
print("Loading: ###....... ", end="\r")
time.sleep(2)
print("Loading: ####...... ", end="\r")
time.sleep(2)
print("Loading: #####..... ", end="\r")
time.sleep(2)
print("Loading: ######.... ", end="\r")
time.sleep(2)
print("Loading: #######... ", end="\r")
time.sleep(2)
print("Loading: ########.. ", end="\r")
time.sleep(2)
print("Loading: #########. ", end="\r")
time.sleep(2)
print("Loading: ########## ", end="\r")
time.sleep(2)
print("Done: ########## \r")
print("Starting Bot")
```

Taking this code block and running it you will see the bar change on  the same line every 2 seconds